# SparkSQL Staging Table Row Count vs Hive Row count

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am attempting to extract data from Cassandra, into a specific partitioned Hive table using Spark 2.1.1 on Hadoop 2.7. To do this, I have all the data from Cassandra into an rdd which I transform into a dataframe via rdd.toDF(), and passed into the following function:

```
public def writeToHive(ss: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) {
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(tablename)
  val cols = df.columns
  val schema = df.schema

  // logs 358
  LOG.info(s"""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${tablename}""")

  val outdf = ss.sql(s"""INSERT INTO TABLE ${db}.${t} PARTITION (date="${destPartition}") SELECT * FROM ${tablename}""")

  // Have also tried the following lines below, but yielded the same results
  // var dfInput_1 = dfInput.withColumn("region", lit(s"${destPartition}"))
  // dfInput_1.write.mode("append").insertInto(s"${db}.${t}")

  // logs 358
  LOG.info(s"""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${tablename}""")
  // logs 423
  LOG.info(s"""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${db}.${t} where date='${destPartition}'""")
}
```

When looking in Cassandra, there are indeed 358 rows in the table. I saw this post on Hortonworks https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/51322/count-msmatch-while-using-the-parquet-file-in-spar.html but there doesn't seem to be a solution. I have tried setting spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning to true, but no changes were seen in the row counts.

Would love any feedback as to why there is a discrepancy between the row counts. Thanks!

EDIT: bad data coming in.... should've seen that coming

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes data contains non-utf8 characters like Japanese or Chinese. Check if data contains any such non-utf8 characters.

If this is a case insert it in ORC format. By default it is text, and text doesn't support non-utf8 characters.

Comment: *"non-utf8 characters like Japanese or Chinese"* - That doesn't make sense. I think you're referring to the fact that UTF-8 and ASCII happen share the same codes for the "English" alphabet. Maybe you should (re)read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)